# libclang -> Get function body of overwritten functions while traversing AST

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, clang

I'm using libclang for parsing C++ Code. The goal is to cut out the implementation of functions which i need for roundtrip engineering in a Code Generator. My code works perfectly for functions that are not overwritten by subclasses. But if i derive Interfaces, the decl->hasBody() function returns false. So how do i get the implementaion of overwritten functions?

So here is my current code:

```
// overwritten function in a Subclass of RecursiveASTVisitor
bool FindNamedClassVisitor::VisitDecl(Decl *decl)
{
if(const CXXMethodDecl* method = dyn_cast<CXXMethodDecl>(decl))
{
    FullSourceLoc FullLocation = Context->getFullLoc(method->getLocStart());
    if (FullLocation.isValid()&& !FullLocation.isInSystemHeader())
    {
        QString name = QString::fromStdString(method->getParent()->getNameAsString()) + "::" + QString::fromStdString(method->getNameAsString());
        if(decl->hasBody())
        {
            QString impl = QString::fromStdString(decl2str(decl->getSourceRange()));

            hash.insert(name, impl);
            qDebug()<<name;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug()<<"NO BODY: "<<name;
        }
    }
}
```

the clang seems to ignore the redeclaration in the derived classes.. The result is that for this functions my code prints "NO BODY:..."

Any suggestions or code snippets?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't seem to be using `libclang`, but rather one of the other [clang interfaces](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html) (libtooling, maybe?). You should consider explicitly mentioning the interface you're using, and retag your question accordingly (maybe `llvm-c++-api`)